# Jquery looping through attribute values

Tags: jquery, if-statement, increment, attr, decrement

In Jquery I'm attempting to increment the attribute value of 5 list items such that their position in the list changes on the click of a forward and backward button, but does not exceed the 5 possible positions, or become a negative integer.

What I was trying to write was a function that checks for values < 5, and increments them by 1, and then decrements 5 by 4 to make it a position of 1, when #forward is clicked. Similarly, for clicking #backward, a function would check for values > 1 and decrement them by 1, and then increment 1 by 4 to make it a position of 5, essentially allowing for a control to loop the 5 list items through the 5 positions.

I'm using the following script:

```
//forward
$("#forward").click(function() {
  if ( $('li').attr('position') < 5 ) {
    $('li').attr('position', function(_, v) {
      return Number(v) + 1;
    });
  } else if ( $('li').attr('position') == 5 ) {
    $('li').attr('position', function(_, v) {
      return Number(v) - 4;
    });
  }
});
//backward
$("#backward").click(function() {
  if ( $('li').attr('position') > 1 ) {
    $('li').attr('position', function(_, v) {
      return Number(v) - 1;
    });
  } else if ( $('li').attr('position') == 1 ) {
    $('li').attr('position', function(_, v) {
      return Number(v) + 4;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to change only the position attribute of the li elements or do you want to change the order of elements in the UI itself ?

Comment: Your *issue* is that `$('li').attr('position')` will always and only give you the attribute from the *first* element.  A `console.log($('li').attr('position'))` would have shown you this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the position of the `if` statement and the `attr` function around, like this:

```
$("#forward").click(function() {
  $('li').attr('position', function(_, v) {
    if ($(this).attr('position') < 5) {
      return Number(v) + 1;
    } else if ($(this).attr('position') == 5) {
      return Number(v) - 4;
    }
  });
});
//backward
$("#backward").click(function() {
  $('li').attr('position', function(_, v) {
    if ($(this).attr('position') > 1) {
      return Number(v) - 1;
    } else if ($(this).attr('position') == 5) {
      return Number(v) + 4;
    }
  });
});
```

After swappering the if and attr, then we will change `$('li').attr('position') < 5` to `$(this).attr('position') < 5`

**Demo**

```js
$("#forward").click(function() {
  $('li').attr('position', function(_, v) {
    if ($(this).attr('position') < 5) {
      return Number(v) + 1;
    } else if ($(this).attr('position') == 5) {
      return Number(v) - 4;
    }
  });
});
//backward
$("#backward").click(function() {
  $('li').attr('position', function(_, v) {
    if ($(this).attr('position') > 1) {
      return Number(v) - 1;
    } else if ($(this).attr('position') == 5) {
      return Number(v) + 4;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-container">
  <ul class="carousel">
    <li id="1" class="story" position="1">1</li>
    <li id="2" class="story" position="5">2</li>
    <li id="3" class="story" position="4">3</li>
    <li id="4" class="story" position="2">4</li>
    <li id="5" class="story" position="3">5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<nav class="control">
  <ul>
    <li id="forward"><a href="#">forward<i class="fa-solid fa-caret-right"></i></a></li>
    <li id="backward"><a href="#">backward<i class="fa-solid fa-caret-left"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the position attribute please try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#forward").on("click", function(){
    $('#list li').each(function(index, item){
      const pos = parseInt($(this).attr('position'));
      const newPos = pos < 5 ? pos+1 : 1;
      console.log(pos, newPos);
      $(this).attr('position', newPos);;
    });
 });
 
  $("#backward").on("click", function(){
    $('#list li').each(function(index, item){
      const pos = parseInt($(this).attr('position'));
      const newPos = pos > 1 ? pos-1 : 5; 
      console.log(pos, newPos)
      $(this).attr('position', newPos);
    });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="backward">backward</div>
<ul id="list">
  <li position="1">1</li>
  <li position="2">2</li>
  <li position="3">3</li>
  <li position="4">4</li>
  <li position="5">5</li>
</ul>
<div id="forward">forward</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b62uzqkf/